# Can't set httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" in webconfig

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I've switech from 2.0 to 4.0 a web application.

I've an issue with validateRequest="false", I need to read an xml files from an aspx page (the page is called by another website and it's not seen by users). It worked fine in 2.0. Now the other website return an error 500.
I ve found on google that in the webconfig system.web, I had to set  but the property requestValidationMode is not valid (and intellisense doesnt show it to me in VS)...

How can I do that?

Thanx

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: What exactly is the 500 error?? It may not actually be related to validateRequest.

Comment: In the server log it says windows event error 3003 wich is related to the request...

Comment: By not allowed I mean VS does'nt propose it in intellisense...

Answer (score 0):

You add this code

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>

Nota : On IIS :  Right click on WebSite 
                 - Select> Properties > ASP.NET > Version > 
                 - Select 4.0.21006 not 2.0
```

Comment: I tried... targetFrameworkand requestValidationMode are not allowed in the webconfig... any idea why?

Comment: @blop, what do you mean by "not allowed"?

Comment: Right click on WebSite 
                 - Select> Properties > ASP.NET > Version > 
                 - Select 4.0.21006 not 2.0